# WiX how to keep site port on major upgrade

Tags: wix

```
<Component Id="IisComponent" Guid="someGuid" Win64="yes" KeyPath="yes">
    <iis:WebSite Directory="INSTALLDIR" AutoStart="yes" Id="WebSite" Description="someDescription" >
    <iis:WebAddress Header="[SITEBINDINGHOST]" Id="WebSiteAddress" IP="*" Port="[SITEBINDINGPORT]" />
    <iis:WebApplication Id="WebApp" Name="someApplicationName" WebAppPool="AppPool" />
    <iis:WebDirProperties Id="DirProperties" WindowsAuthentication="yes" AnonymousAccess="no" LogVisits="yes" />
    </iis:WebSite>
    <some other blocks />
</Component>
```

I mean the real current value of site binding in IIS.
I have already solved a similar problem by using a custom actions (save the value before uninstalling, restore after installing). Maybe there's another way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I do:

During first install it AppSearch will try to find a value in the given registry key, but it won't find anything, then the property will be set to the default value.

During major upgrade, AppSearch will find a value in the given registry key and set the property to that value.

```
<Property Id="WEBSITEPORT" Value="80">
    <RegistrySearch Id="WebSitePortSearch" Type="raw" Root="HKLM" Key="$(var.RootKey)\$(var.IISWebSiteKey)" Name="Port"/>
</Property>
```

All these registry keys will be present when you launch your upgrade installer and will be set before the old version gets uninstalled.

Now you need to create the registry keys during your installation, something like this:

```
<Component Id="CommonWebSiteRegistry">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="$(var.RootKey)\IIS Config" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Description" Value="[WEBSITEDESCRIPTION]"/>
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Port" Value="[WEBSITEPORT]"/>
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="HostName" Value="[HOSTNAME]"/>
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="AppPool" Value="[APPPOOLNAME]"/>
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="AppPoolRuntimeVersion" Value="$(var.ASPRuntime)"/>
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="PhisicalDir" Value="[WebSiteRoot]"/>
    </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

As you can see you can create as many registry keys/values to store your initial settings and you can read them with your installer during major upgrades.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to use the currently configured port on IIS you will need to use a Custom Action combined with the solution I mentioned above.

Your Custom Action will require an input parameter with the "Web site name" you will have to retrieve it from the registry and then pass it to your CA as CustomActionData.

Once you retrieve the port configured in IIS you will need to update your [SITEBINDINGPORT] property with the new value, after that the previous implementation I recommended will do the trick using the appropriate value.

Comment: (sorry for my bad English) I have kept the port value in the registry. But if I change the port value in the site settings, in the registry will be the old value, and it will be restored on upgrade. I have to keep the current value of the binding.